# MaxHeap and MinHeap in the Go standard library

Tags: go, heap

1) Why does Go's standard library [heap](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap) does not have implementation of MaxHeap and it looks like it supports only MinHeap?

2) In the above implementation, which `function` is responsible for `Heapify()`? `Heapify()` converts a normal array into a Heap in `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes, makes more sense now.

Comment: "Why" questions can only be answered by the designers. "How" questions can be answered by the community.

Comment: I have no idea What is so offenside about this question. I could not find any other place to reach out to the community of the question i had.

Answer (score 5):

It supports both by letting you implement a `Less` function comparing two elements. If your `Less(i,j)` returns true if `i<j`, then it is a minheap. If your `Less(i,j)` returns false if `i<j` then it is a maxheap. Heapify would be `heap.Init`.